# SQL query to locate and remove spam content from a SQL injection hack

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress website that was hacked.
The hacker inserted hidden HTML in my posts (wp_posts table) using this HTML pattern:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:1px;">
<p>Text here, always different</p>
<p>More text....</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to locate in the DB everything that starts with

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:1px;">
```

and ends in the next

```
</div>
```

and then remove these entries from the DB?

Note: I have access to phpMyAdmin.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you please run the SQL query `SELECT VERSION();` in a MySQL client and report what it returns?

Comment: @BillKarwin it's version 5.7.39-42-log . cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could start by selecting every column that has that div in it

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column1 + column2 + column3 LIKE '%<div style="overflow:hidden;height:1px;">%'
```

If that brings up everything

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE column1 + column2 + column3 LIKE '%<div style="overflow:hidden;height:1px;">%'
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess that wouldn't get the whole content inside the div, until the div closing tag </div>

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant remove the offending code block from each post, and not

> remove these entries from the DB

**Important**

1. This approach will only work when there are no other divs nested within the one described.
2. Make sure you have a useable backup before going any further.

```
SELECT
    id,
    post_content,
    REPLACE(
        post_content,
        CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(post_content, INSTR(post_content, '<div style="overflow:hidden;height:1px;">')), '</div>', 1), '</div>'),
        ''
    ) cleaned
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_content LIKE '%<div style="overflow:hidden;height:1px;">%</div>%';
```

Do a thorough check on the results to make sure you are happy with the transformation from `post_content` to `cleaned`. If all looks good, take a backup of wp_posts, and do the update -

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(
        post_content,
        CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(post_content, INSTR(post_content, '<div style="overflow:hidden;height:1px;">')), '</div>', 1), '</div>'),
        ''
    )
WHERE post_content LIKE '%<div style="overflow:hidden;height:1px;">%</div>%';
```